# Auto play and next each song after each song fishish on wpf 8.1. How do that?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8

Here is code play music when choosen item on listbox but i don't know do auto playing and next each song....

```
private void lst_album_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentSongindex != -1)
        {
            currentSongindex = lst_album.SelectedIndex;
        }
        currentSongindex++;
        if (currentSongindex < lst_album.Items.Count)
        {
            mymedia.Source = new Uri((lst_album.SelectedItem as Data.Data).link);
            mymedia.Play();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put logic to play next song on current song finished in `MediaEnded` event handler method.

XAML :

```
<MediaElement Name="mymedia" MediaEnded="mymedia_MediaEnded"
    ......... />
```

Code-behind :

```
private void mymedia_MediaEnded(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //check if next song available, play next song
    if (currentSongindex < lst_album.Items.Count)
    {
        mymedia.Source = new Uri((lst_album.Items[currentSongindex] as Data.Data).link);
        mymedia.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sr.It still Not automaticaly next song.

Comment: and show error about "new Uri((lst_album.Items[currentSongindex] as Data.Data)" at currentsongindex

Comment: mymedia.Source = new Uri((lst_album.SelectedItem[currentSongindex] as Data.Data).link);
Error:Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'

Comment: look at the answer again, it should've been `...lst_album.Items[currentSongindex]...`